# ¿Por qué el archivo google-services.json de firebase está desaparecido?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, gradle

Tengo el siguiente error, he copiado y pegado las librerias de un antiguo proyecto en el nuevo, e hecho los pasos en el gradle app pero me arroja error, estoy seguro que es un problema con el archivo de json ya que puede haber conflicto. Me creé un proyecto nuevo en firebase con un archivo json nuevo y lo puse no se que mas hacer....

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

...

```
Searched Location: 
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/src/debug/google-services.json
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
    /Users/Brian/AndroidStudioProjects/Buceo/app/google-services.json
```

Answer (score 1):

El archivo json se debe generar en la página de desarrollo de Firebase. Dejo el enlace de las intrucciones [aqui](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).

Cuando el archivo esté descargado se coloca en la app a nivel del projecto y no en src.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es suficiente para que android studio encuentre la referencia. Saludos.